# log4net creates log file but does not write to it

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-services, log4net

I am trying to use basic logging for a windows service.

I added the reference to log4net.

I added the following in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

I added the following to my App.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <!-- Log4net Logging Setup -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="c:\\CGSD\\log\\logfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I have the following code in my service:

```
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

    log.Debug("test");
```

The file `c:\CGSD\log\logfile.txt` is created but nothing is ever written to it.

I've been through the forums all day trying to track this one down, but if I overlooked an already posted solution I apologize.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the log.Debug line, do you reach that line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your filter level looks to be configured at `<levelMin value="INFO" />` but you are testing a `log.Debug` message.  Change your configuration to have `<levelMin value="DEBUG" />` and try again.  If that doesn't fix it, there may be other config problems also.

Comment: That did it.  I changed <levelMin value="DEBUG" /> and now i can see entries in my log file.

Answer (score 0):

You require a minimum level  `INFO` and are trying to log a message with level `DEBUG`. As you can see in the documentation (http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html), the priority of `DEBUG` is lower than `INFO` so your message is filtered out.

Comment: That did it. I changed <levelMin value="DEBUG" /> and now i can see entries in my log file.